# Treat data of a XML file using FileProvider

Tags: java, android, xml, fileprovider

I want to read an `XML` file stored in downloads using the `Android` app I am developing.

I want to use **File Provider** to search for it but once I find it, I want to know the real path of that `XML` file in order to parse it and treat it.

How can I make this? 
I've tried many things but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the URI provided by the file provider

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

and pass the input string using **xml** parser library